# Integral representation of completely alternating homogeneous functionals on semi-lattice of continuous functions

Tags: rt.representation-theory, real-analysis, lattices, extremal-set-theory, extreme-points

For a long time I've been interested in G. Choquet seminal work "**Theory of capacities**" (Annales de l’institut Fourier, tome 5 (1954), p. 131-295). More precisely part 53 about **integral representation** (in Choquet sense) of positively homogeneous functionals **altenating** of order $\infty$ over the max operation $\vee$ of the continuous functions with compact support $\varphi\in Q^+$, denoted by $A$. For this it is needed to describe the set $e(A)$ of **extremal elements** of the cone $A$. In 53.1 Choquet claims *without proof* that $e(A)$ consists only of the functionals $f\in A$ with the property $f(\varphi_1)=f(\varphi_1)\implies f(\varphi_1\vee\varphi_1)=f(\varphi_1)=f(\varphi_1)$ (so called **max-functionals**). Then these functionals are used by him to prove integral representation of elements of $A$. But I found the counterexample that, max-functional is not an extremal element of $A$ ($\not\in e(A)$). At most max-functionals form **extremal set** and the subsequent facts in part 53 should be reconsidered. Are there successors' works on Choquet's integral representation of $A$? I found only results *without homogeneity*, that are the variants of Bernstein theorem.